# get error when using sum and case in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using `sqlalchemy` `func.sum` with `case` in a `having` condition but get below error.
code:

```
query = query.having(
            func.sum(case([(e.c.escalation_type.in_(escalation_types), 1)], else_=0)) > 0
        )
```

`escalation_types` above is Python list
get this error:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedFunctionError: function sum(text) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Here is the `SQL` printed by above:

```
HAVING sum(CASE WHEN (escalation_1.escalation_type IN (:escalation_type_1)) THEN :param_1 ELSE :param_2 END) > :sum_1
```

what am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the SQL being sent to the DB?

Comment: added it. please see above.

Comment: Seems to be suggesting that you are trying to `SUM` a text column?

Comment: That's what looks like but as you can see I'm passing 1 (if case is true) and 0 (if case is not true) so they're clearly integer, not clear why it complains they're text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug in one of the libraries of `sqlalchemy`, `asyncpg`. I have to cast 1 and 0 to integer to make it work. here is working code:

```
query = query.having(
            func.sum(
                case(
                    [(e.c.escalation_type.in_(escalation_types), cast(1, Integer))],
                    else_=cast(0, Integer),
                )
            )
            > 0
        )
```

Comment: I wonder if the bug is in asyncpg, I think SQLA should forward the integers as such to the DB-API layer.